# Ho do I remove the data after an event?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my data, I wish to remove all the data for an ID after an event

```
ID   Event  time
1      0     1
1      1     2
2      0     3
1      0     4
2      0     5
```

Since for ID number 1 , the event was greater than 0, I'd like to remove all the next data of ID 1. So, I remove row number 4 and my ideal output will be

```
 ID   Event  time
  1     0     1
  1     1     2
  2     0     3
  2     0     5
```

How can I do that?

```
 dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Event = c(0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), time = 1:5), .Names = c("ID", "Event", "time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I tried something very complicated and created tow set of datasets for those who had event and for those who did not had, I assigned a time series to both of them and did `output<-filter(mydata, is.na(Time.y) | last (Time.y) > last (Time.x) )` and after all it didn't give me my desired output.  I thought perhaps there is a simple way that I'm missing

Comment: I'm assuming that's `dplyr::filter`, not `stats::filter`. With dplyr, `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(time <= min(which(Event == 1)))` works.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire . You are awesome!

Comment: Oops, that should probably be `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(time <= min(time[Event == 1]))`, actually. Base R: `df[as.logical(ave(df$Event, df$ID, FUN = function(x){seq_along(x) <= min(which(x == 1))})), ]` Note both depend on `min(numeric(0))` returning `Inf`; account for the empty case explicitly if you prefer.

Comment: Greate. Please consider  writing your answer below. It's readable and beautiful and worked very well for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With dplyr, you can `filter` for `time` values less than the minimum one where `Event` is 1, grouped by `ID`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(time <= min(time[Event == 1]))

## Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
## Groups: ID [2]
## 
##      ID Event  time
##   <int> <int> <int>
## 1     1     0     1
## 2     1     1     2
## 3     2     0     3
## 4     2     0     5
```

Instead of using `time`, you could use `row_number` or `seq` with `which`. In base R, you could use `ave` to handle the grouping, but it can only handle one input vector, so a `seq` approach is simpler than working with `time`:

```
df[as.logical(ave(df$Event, df$ID, FUN = function(x) {
    seq_along(x) <= min(which(x == 1))
})), ]

##   ID Event time
## 1  1     0    1
## 2  1     1    2
## 3  2     0    3
## 5  2     0    5
```

Both approaches depend on the fact that `min(integer(0))` returns `Inf` when there is no 1 values for an `ID`, but add an `if` condition to explicitly account for the situation, if you like.

Comment: I thought there must be something simple here, but I couldn't really better it. My best attempt was `df[!ave(df$Event, df$ID, FUN=function(x) rev(cumsum(rev(x))) == 0 & any(x)),]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `match` with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[seq_len(match(1, Event, nomatch = .N))], ID]
#   ID Event time
#1:  1     0    1
#2:  1     1    2
#3:  2     0    3
#4:  2     0    5
```